# Windows fprintf not printing to the file

Tags: c, io, printf, fopen

This program was working flawless on MAC a second ago and now i'm trying to move it over to windows and do some things with windows but the fprintf doesn't work. The file is created but never written to

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int result;
    const char *file = "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\dloaded.ini";
    result = access(file, 00);
    FILE * fp;
    int lines = 0;
    char online[7] = "online";
    char line[155];
    if (result != -1) {
        fprintf(stdout, "\nFile %s exists\n", file);
        fp = fopen(file, "r+");
        while (!feof(fp)) {
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
            if (strstr(line, online) == 0) {
                //Client is not connected!
                fclose(fp);
                fp = fopen(file, "r+");
                fprintf(fp, "%s", online);
                fclose(fp);
                fprintf(stdout, "Now opening sock...\n Sock Opened!\n");
                //main();
            }
            else {
                //Client is already online
                printf("%s is online\n", file);
                fclose(fp);
                getch();
                exit(0);
            }
            //lines++;
        }
    }
    else {
        int result1;
        FILE * fpoint;
        fpoint = fopen(file, "w");
        fclose(fpoint);
        result1 = access(file, 00);
        if (result1 != -1) {
            printf("\n File Created!\n");
            main();
        }
        else {
            printf("File not created");
            getch();
            exit(0);
        };
    };

}
```

Comment: You'll want to put in error checking as to whether or not your fopen calls are actually working...

Comment: Well it creates the file fine so i'd expect they are working

Comment: You can also check the number of characters printed, as returned by fprintf.

Comment: First time round, 'while (!feof(fp)) {' result of compare is undefined.   You need to read first, check feof after.  There's a dup for this but you probably have other stuff wrong...